# Convert double toLocal8Bit

Tags: c++, qt, double, qstring

I'm not really a C++ developer.

I'm trying to convert a double to `local8Bit` for `qDebug`.

Eg:

```
// This works because m_desc is a QString
qDebug("Description: " + m_desc.toLocal8Bit());

// This doesn't work because m_price is a double
qDebug("Price: " + m_price.toLocal8Bit());
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct,
[QString::toLocal8Bit](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toLocal8Bit)
works on strings only.
Try [QString::number](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#number-6)
instead.

From the documentation:

```
QString::number(double n, char format = 'g', int precision = 6)
```

Example implementation:

```
qDebug() << QString::number(m_price);
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of how I can implement this to get my `qDebug` to work?

Comment: Edited my answer to include an example implementation.

Comment: I tried this:  `qDebug() << QString::number(m_price);` and it gives the following error -> `invalid use of incomplete type 'class QDebug'`

Comment: This is what I ended up doing:  `qDebug("Price: " + QString::number(m_price).toLocal8Bit());` to get it to work.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you included the QDebug class? Also check [QDebug](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.5/qdebug.html) for basic use of QDebug.

Comment: But: why would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

There's no reason to do any of that. Feed the numbers directly to `qDebug`. That class was designed to be easy to use to quickly get the output you need:

```
qDebug() << "Price:" << m_price;
```

If you need to have control over the exact formatting of the number, use `QString::number`:

```
qDebug() << "Price:" << QString::number(m_price, 'f', 2);
```